# why is there problem without windowClosing

Tags: java

I know that this program needs window Closing function to close the frame but I don't know why 
explanation would be helpful

```
public class NoLayoutDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Frame frame= new Frame("no layout teset");
   frame.setLayout(null);
   frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
        System.exit(0);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to java documentation

```
WINDOW_CLOSING:
If the program doesn't explicitly hide or dispose the window while processing this 
event, the window close operation is canceled.
```

Then you have to do the close operation yourself, otherwise the close operation has no effect.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Maybe like this?

```
   public class NoLayoutDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Frame frame = new Frame("no layout teset");
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setSize(200, 300);
            frame.show();
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
                    frame.dispose();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```